# Interrupt the arduino micro-controller, on receiving a text message in GSM SIM900 module

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, sim900

Is there any way to interrupt the arduino if a new message arrives in SIM 900 module? In my project, a lot of tasks are going on, so I need the GSM module to interrupt the ardiuino, if a new message comes, and act according to my requirement. How do I do that?